# What is considered to be current and latest state in kafka state stores?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-interactive-queries

I'm trying to understand what state should be expected from KTables.

I was reading [interactive queries documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) and it says

> This store will hold the latest count for any word that is found on
>   the topic “word-count-input”.

Let's say a message is successfully sent to a topic T

1. Does it mean that all interactive queries on a table that was built from T are guaranteed to see the changes immediately? ( built as builder.table("T",...) )?
2. Does it mean that all interactive queries on a table that was aggregated from T are guaranteed to see the changes immediately? ( built as builder.stream("T").groupByKey().aggregate(...) )?

And this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/join-semantics-in-kafka-streams) says:

> The KTable lookup is always done on the current state of the KTable;
>   thus, out-of-order records can yield a non-deterministic result.

Given that:

- stream S1 was built as builder.stream("T")
- table T1 was built as S1.groupByKey().aggregate(...)
- stream S2 is S1 joined with T1

3. Is it guaranteed that the join operation will always happen after aggregation so every new record is always aggregated first and then joined and never vice versa?

**Added**:

My main question here is when data are available to be requested through interactive queries or joins. Is it possible to get stale data/is there a possibility for a lag?

Answer (score 3):

If a message is successfully sent to a topic T.

1. Yes, state stores are always updated with the latest value for a given key. As soon as `builder.table("T",...)` receives a new update on existing key, interactive query will return a new value.
2. Yes, all the state stores which are somehow linked with topic T will be updated based on new update. `builder.stream("T").groupByKey().aggregate(...) )` will also update the state store beneath.
3. In case of  `S1 =  builder.stream("T"), T1 = S1.groupByKey().aggregate(...), S2 =S1.join(T1)`, it follows Stream-Table join semantics. Updates on the KTable, will always update the internal right side join state, but the join operation will be triggered only when there are some new records on Stream(left side)

Here is the nice example for KStream-KTable join semantics: 
https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#kstream-ktable-join

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My main concern was whether or not the changes will be immediately available, meaning that the lag between message send and interactive query is impossible.
For example is it possible to get stale data if a message was persisted in kafka and then requested right after? Unfortunately it is not clear from your answer. Looks like I formulated it poorly so I'll add clarification.

Comment: I see, When the event is updated in KTable, it updates the underlying state store at the same time, and the interactive query should return new value instead of stale one. Ideally there should not be any lag.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging found an answer for the third part:

3. For every new message that comes to the input topic, that message goes through the whole topology in the order that was used when the topology was created and then all changes are committed in a single transaction. That's why the message is always persisted in ktable first and only after that the message is joined. So in the version I used for testing the lag is impossible since it is a single thread and a single transaction and the order is defined.

Here is an example:

Test class:

```
package myapps;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.test.ConsumerRecordFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Properties;

public class TopologyTest {

    private static final String INPUT_TOPIC = "input-topic";
    private static final String OUTPUT_TOPIC = "output-topic";

    @Test
    public void testStreams() {

        Topology topology = createTopology();

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Long().getClass().getName());

        try (TopologyTestDriver testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, config)) {

            ConsumerRecordFactory<String, Long> factory = new ConsumerRecordFactory<>(
                    INPUT_TOPIC, new StringSerializer(), new LongSerializer());

            testDriver.pipeInput(factory.create(INPUT_TOPIC, "key", 1L));
            testDriver.pipeInput(factory.create(INPUT_TOPIC, "key", 2L));
            testDriver.pipeInput(factory.create(INPUT_TOPIC, "key", 3L));

            ProducerRecord<String, String> pr1 = testDriver.readOutput(OUTPUT_TOPIC, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
            ProducerRecord<String, String> pr2 = testDriver.readOutput(OUTPUT_TOPIC, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
            ProducerRecord<String, String> pr3 = testDriver.readOutput(OUTPUT_TOPIC, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());

            Assert.assertEquals("1,1", pr1.value());
            Assert.assertEquals("2,3", pr2.value());
            Assert.assertEquals("3,6", pr3.value());
        }
    }

    private Topology createTopology() {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Long> inputStream = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);

        KTable<String, Long> table = inputStream.groupByKey().aggregate(
                () -> 0L,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> value + aggregate,
                Materialized.as("store")
        );

        KStream<String, String> joined = inputStream
                .join(table, (value, aggregate) -> value + "," + aggregate);

        joined.to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Kafka dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```